# let $F(X)=\int_0^x \sin\frac{1}{1+t^2}\,dt$, then which of these is correct?

Tags: calculus

a) $0 \le F(x)$ for all $x$. 
b) $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac {F(x)}{x} = 1$
c) $\lim_{x \to \infty} F(x)= \infty $ 
d) $F$ has an inverse and $(F^{-1})'(0)=\frac{1}{\sin 1}$ 
What I did: for (a)  I went for the derivative $F'(x)=\sin\frac{1}{1+x^2}$, I saw that it's bigger than zero and it's decreasing, could just infer that the function $F(x)$ is increasing, and not $F(x)\ge0$ for all x, so I left it aside. 
(b) I took the limit and it was $0$, so it's wrong. 
(c) I think I thought a little too broad here and just said that $\sin\frac{1}{1+x^2}$, is like $\frac{1}{x^2}$, which converges if the integral was from $1 \to \infty$, not from zero. 
(d) I tried to do this $F((F^{-1})'(0))$, which is supposed to give me $0$, but I didn't get zero. so I assumed its wrong. 
 In the end the answer was (d), I would really appreciate an explanation of why it is true, hence $F((F^{-1})'(0))\ne0$, also I would appreciate any tips about my thinking and the way I tried to solve the question. 
 Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**

Let $$f : t\mapsto \sin(\frac{1}{1+t^2})$$

$ f $ is defined and is continuous at $ \Bbb R $, thus $ F $ is differentiable at $ \Bbb R $ and
$$(\forall x\in \Bbb R)\;\; F'(x)=f(x)>0$$
because
$$(\forall x\in \Bbb R)\;\;0<\frac{1}{1+x^2}\le 1<\frac{\pi}{2}$$

So,  $ F $ is continuous and strictly increasing at $ \Bbb R$ , then it has an inverse satisfying

$$(F^{-1})'(0)=\frac{1}{F'(F^{-1}(0))}$$

$$=\frac{1}{F'(0)}=\frac{1}{f(0)}=\frac{1}{\sin(1)}$$

Remark
$$F(0)=0\implies F^{-1}(0)=0$$

Comment: Really appreciate the answer! now I get where I made a mistake, I took it as the inverse to the derivative instead of the function itself. thank you

Comment: You are Welcome .

Answer (score 1):

That comes from the [inverse function theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function_theorem#Statement) that
$$
(F^{-1})'(0)=\frac{1}{F'(F^{-1}(0))}
$$

---

Notes.

By the fundamental theorem of calculus, $\displaystyle F'(x)=\sin \frac{1}{1+x^2}$. On the other hand, $F(0)=0$, which tells you what $F^{-1}(0)$ is.